# Why are the columns of my Bootstrap 4 grid not the same height and width?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid, col

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and want to make a grid view. The problem is that my columns don't have the same width. Also, the height of the columns are not the same as you can see on the borders.
I've read that the columns in Bootstrap 4 should have the same height and width natively, but somehow it seems not to work for me. I'd be glad if someone could help me.

[image]

Here's the code of my grid.

```css
.grid-header {
  background-color: #002f5a;
  color: white;
  height: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.grid-header .col-sm {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.grid-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.grid-column-value {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.grid-filter {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.grid-filter-column {}

.grid-edit-form {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.grid-edit-row {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.grid-row.selected,
.grid-row:hover {
  background-color: #002f5a;
  color: white;
}

.grid-action-column {
  float: right;
}

.grid-action-column>.btn {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.grid-edit-btn {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-edit-btn:hover {
  background-color: #ebd234;
}

.grid-delete-btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.grid-delete-btn:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
}

.grid-edit-form-buttons {
  float: right;
}

.grid-edit-form-buttons>.btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="grid-header row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">Identifier</div>
    <div class="col">Der Name</div>
    <div class="col">Beschreibung</div>
    <div class="col">E-Mail</div>
    <div class="col">Link</div>
    <div class="col">Erstellt am: </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-filter row">
    <div class="col grid-filter-column">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><i class="input-group-text fas fa-filter"></i></div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup-Id-filter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col grid-filter-column">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><i class="input-group-text fas fa-filter"></i></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup-Name-filter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col grid-filter-column">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><i class="input-group-text fas fa-filter"></i></div>
        <input type="" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup-Description-filter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col grid-filter-column">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><i class="input-group-text fas fa-filter"></i></div>
        <input type="" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup-EmailAddress-filter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col grid-filter-column">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><i class="input-group-text fas fa-filter"></i></div>
        <input type="" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup-TestUrl-filter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col grid-filter-column">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><i class="input-group-text fas fa-filter"></i></div>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup-CreatedAt-filter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col grid-filter-column"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-row row align-items-center" id="grid-row-1">
    <div class="col grid-column-value">1</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">Hans</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">This is some cool description</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">hans.peter@example.net</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value"><a href="https://www.google.de/">https://www.google.de/</a></div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">05.08.2020 13:53:25</div>
    <div class="col grid-action-column"><button class="btn grid-edit-btn" onclick="ShowEditRow('http://localhost:5005/Home/CallApi?Id=1', '1');"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button><a href="http://localhost:5005/Home/CallApi?Id=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" class="btn grid-delete-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-row row align-items-center" id="grid-row-2">
    <div class="col grid-column-value">2</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">Laura</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">This is another cool description</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">laura.g@example.net</div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value"><a href="https://www.google.de/">https://www.google.de/</a></div>
    <div class="col grid-column-value">05.08.2020 13:53:25</div>
    <div class="col grid-action-column"><button class="btn grid-edit-btn" onclick="ShowEditRow('http://localhost:5005/Home/CallApi?Id=2', '2');"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button><a href="http://localhost:5005/Home/CallApi?Id=2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" class="btn grid-delete-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I noticed that this problem is only occuring, if the content of my columns is too long. E.g. if the description is displayed in two lines. I don't want to use "text-truncate", because the content won't be fully shown then.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `w-100` after each row to make them equal.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">col</div>
    <div class="col">col</div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col">col</div>
    <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you putting them in the same `.row`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think it might be something different in my code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I've found an answer.

The problem with the width was that the "emails" were too long and because they were "one word" (no spaces in-between) they could not got broken. So I added the following line to my css:

```
.grid-column-value {
    ...
    word-break: break-word;
    ...
}
```

You can solve this problem with different solutions like the `.text-truncate` class from Bootstrap. It depends on your needs and preferences.

For the height I got problems because I added the class `.align-items-center` to my row. To solve this I removed the class from it and added following lines to my css:

```
.grid-column-value {
    ...
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.grid-action-column {
    ...
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This basically does the same as `.align-items-center` but directly targets the columns instead of the whole row.

The whole grid now looks like this:
[image]